# Roll up result of Cross Apply in correlated subquery

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery, cross-apply

I have a table which looks like this (T1)

```
Columns    PolicyElementID, PolicyRuleID, ElementID, Value
    
row1    (1, 86, 2, '53, 18, 17, 24, 25, 95, 51, 64, 9, 6645')
    
row2    (2, 246, 39, '10, 5, 7, 12, 3, 2, 16, 1006')
```

The values are foreign keys in multiple tables, depending on that ElementID and pull out the relevant rows there.
I know the whole table should be normalized but that's the DEVs, not me.

Now I am working on a migration script to insert or copy these values to another DB, where of course the value would be different as IDs will not be aligned.

```
select
T1.PolicyElementId, T1.PolicyRuleId,  T1.ElementID, T1.Value,
T2.CodeName, T2.DataType, T2.Multivalue, T3.Codename
            (SELECT '; ' + Codename
            FROM T3
            WHERE T3.ID =  tvf.value
            FOR XML PATH('')) [RollUp]

from
T1

left join T2 on T1.ElementID = T2.ElementID
left join T3 ON T1.PolicyRuleId = T3.PolicyRuleId
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(T1.Value, ',')a
```

So I thought I would cross apply a STRING SPLIT and join the relevant table to it, which works just fine.

I had been searching for a simple way to roll up the results again and found this:

[Rolling up multiple rows into a single row and column for SQL Server data](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/)

This uses the FOR XML definitions and formats them to do get bank text out. But I cannot get it to work in conjunction with the Cross Apply.

Any ideas?

Best
D

Comment: I'm lost at what `T1` looks like.  Please put the table into rows and columns so it is clear what is what.

Comment: I have added this, hope that helps.

Comment: `tvf.value` but I see not `tvf` table or alias. Am I missing something ?

Comment: This is meant to represent the STRING SPLIT value, that is where I am stuck.

Comment: shouldn't it be `a.vlaue`  since you use `a` as an alias for the `STRING_SPLIT`?